# VisualStudioEnterprise: is team service account a must to do load test?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

When I tried Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 to do load tests, it automatically connects to some website and asks for a team service account.

I don't have one and my environment does not have an Internet connection.

Can I do load tests without such an account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every month or so Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise requires the user to validate their license. That is quickly done via some network activity. The trial version of the software is just an unlicensed version that has some restrictions on the type of load tests that can be done.

Assuming that the license has been validated and that, I believe, does require a suitable account to have been connected: The default settings for load tests are to use Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS - previously called VSO for Visual Studio Online). Use of VSTS does require a suitable account.

You should be able to run a load test locally on your computer. The setting for local versus VSTS execution of a load test is in the "General" section of the `.testsettings` file.

Comment: Many thanks. I found the config item in the test settings file.